# MockK Mocking a Surface object for Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mocking

I'm trying to test some code, and I need a valid `Surface` object for Android in order to properly test it, since a lot of the code checks if there is a valid surface (ie `surface.isValid()` where surface is of the Surface class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface)

With MockK, is there a way I can essentially perform this Mock? I have tried the following:

```
private lateinit var mymonitor : Monitor
@MockK private lateinit var mockContext : Context
@MockK private lateinit var mockSurface : Surface

@Before
fun setup() {
   init(this, relaxed = true)
   mockkConstructor(Monitor::class)
   mockkConstructor(Surface::class)
   every { anyConstructed<Monitor>().getApplicationContext() } returns mockContext
   every { anyConstructed<Surface>().isValid() } returns true

   mymonitor = spyk(Monitor())
   mymonitor.init(mockContext, mockSurface)
```

In the Monitor.java file

```
protected void init(Context mockContext, Surface mockSurface) {
   if (mockSurface.isValid()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Surface is valid...");
      // proceeds with init
   } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Surface NOT valid...");
   }
}
```

When I do this, I get the Log that `Surface NOT valid`, so basically the Surface object is not valid I suppose. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you mocked the surface before `mymonitor.init`? Like `every{ mockSurface.isValid() } returns true` ?

Comment: I actually just tried that, I updated my code but it was still logging as Surface not valid

Comment: Don't do `anyConstructed<Surface>()`, you have your own mock - `mockSurface`. So do it using it `every{ mockSurface.isValid() } returns true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the anyConstructed:

```
private lateinit var myMonitor : Monitor
private val mockContext : Context = mockk(relaxed = true)
private val mockSurface : Surface = mockk(relaxed = true)

@Before
fun setup() {
    every { mockSurface.isValid() } returns true

    myMonitor = spyk(Monitor())
    myMonitor.init(mockContext, mockSurface)
}
```

PD: In case of needing to use a real context, it would be necessary to apply Robolectric or an android test.